# Does using @Transactional disable the grails default transaction management

Tags: grails, transactions

According to the grails docs, services are transactional by default. But, I know you can get more fine grained control of transactions by using the `Transactional` attribute.

If I have a service such as

```
class MyService {

    @Transactional(...config...)
    def method1() { }

    def method2() { }

}
```

My understanding is that in this case, `method1` will be transactional, but `method2` will not.

If I have

```
class MyService {

    def method1() { }
    def method2() { }

}
```

Then both `method1` and `method2` will both be transactional.

Is this correct?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you want your service as transactional set to true the transactional property (this isn't obligatory but if you want to make clear that the service is transactional):

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = true

    def method1() { }
    def method2() { }

}
```

If you don't want to:

```
class MyService {

    static transactional = false

    @Transactional(...config...)
    def method1() { }

    def method2() { }

}
```

Another example (setting transactional property isn't obligatory, but helps to be clear - if you are not the only coding this):

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
class BookService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def listBooks() {
        Book.list()
    }

    @Transactional
    def updateBook() {
        // â€¦
    }

    def deleteBook() {
        // â€¦
    }
}
```

Another thing you can do is annotate the whole class and override the methods you need to be different:

```
import org.springframework.transaction.annotation.Transactional
@Transactional
class BookService {

    @Transactional(readOnly = true)
    def listBooks() {
        Book.list()
    }

    def updateBook() {
        // â€¦
    }

    def deleteBook() {
        // â€¦
    }
}
```

Hope this helps ;)

Comment: What happens if the static transactional is not specified but the @Transactional annotation is used?

Comment: Thanks, so in the first BookService, deleteBook is not transactional, correct?

Comment: exactly.. listBooks is readonly, update is read-write and delete not transactional ;)

Answer (score 1):

You can disable the Grails default transaction management using `withTransaction` closure for domains to manage your Transaction manually as follows:

```
Account.withTransaction { status ->
    try {
        //write your code or business logic here
    } catch (Exception e) {
        status.setRollbackOnly()
    }
}
```

If an exception is thrown, then the Transaction will be rollbacked.

Comment: I never understood this structure.  Why is it tied to a domain object?  What if I want to have a manually managed transaction like this, but not relevant to a particular domain object, or pertaining to two different objects?  What is the difference between Rollback and RollbackOnly.  Only?